# Use $^I and supply arguments

Tags: perl, file, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to perform some inplace editing. And I have a basic snippet that works for when I have hard coded substitute in place. I am trying to generalize the script by passing in variables now and it fails.

my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;


$^I = '.bak';
my $pow = shift;
my $pres = shift;
my $temp = shift; 
#my $dir= shift || '.';
#my $fileName = "$dir/input.dat";
#open DATA, $fileName or die "Cannot open $fileName for read :$!";
while (<>){
s/^\s+tfwi\s+=\s+\d+.\d+E?[+-]?\d+/   tfwi = $temp/;
s/^\s+RP\s+=\s+\d+.\d+E?[+-]?\d+/   RP = $pow/ig;
s/^\s+pdome\s+=\s+\d+.\d+E?[+-]?\d+/   pdome = $pres/ig;
print;
}
```

i call the script with the following command line entry **"perl inputupdate.pl input.dat 2 3 4"**. The code will look spit out **"Can't open 4: No such file"** It works fine if I just supply a file at the command line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
my $pow = shift;
my $pres = shift;
my $temp = shift;
```

- This assigns `input.dat` to `$pow`,
- assigns `2` to `$pres`,
- assigns `3` `$temp`, and
- leaves `4` in `@ARGV`.

---

Solution 1: Change the parameters to match the code.

```
perl inputupdate.pl 2 3 4 input.dat
```

Solution 2: Change the code to match the parameters.

```
my ($pow, $pres, $temp) = splice(@ARGV, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`input.dat` gets shifted to `$pow`.

`2` gets shifted to `$pres`.

`3` gets shifted to `$temp`.

There are no more shifts, so `4` remains in `@ARGV`, and is interpreted as the filename for the filehandle `ARGV` read by the diamon operator `<>`.

Comment: so do I supply the file last? how can i supply the arguments and still use that $^I?

Comment: @TheCodeNovice: Yes, the file**s** go last (or use `pop`).

Answer (score 1):

Perl sets ARGV to ('input.dat', 2, 3 ,4) and processes the args in that order, so move your file name to the end of the arg list and run:

```
 perl inputupdate.pl 2 3 4 input.dat
```